# Morera's Theorem on Integrals

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Use Morera's theorem and an interchange of the order of integration to show that the following function is analytic on the indicated domain; find a power-series expansion for the function by using the known power series for the integrand and interchanging the summation and integration

$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1/2} \operatorname{Log}(1-tz)~dt \;$
 on |z|<2

$\displaystyle\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \operatorname{Sin}(z+t)~dt \;$
for all $z$

Kindly help me out with the second part. I am comfortable with answering the first part about using Morera's theorem to show that the function is analytic. I have a problem with setting up the power series. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use the power series $ \log(1-t z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty - \frac{( z t)^n}{n} $, which is valid for $ | z t|  < 1 $ and, since $ |z| < 2 $, for all $ t \in [0,\frac{1}{2}] $. So we have:
$$
\int_{0}^{1/2} \log(1 - t z) dt  = - \int_{0}^{1/2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{( z t)^n}{n} dt \\ = - \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \int_{0}^{1/2}  \frac{( z t)^n}{n} dt \\ =  -\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^{n+1} n (n+1)} z^n $$
The second example is similar, just a different series for $ \sin $. I hope this will help!

Comment: Thanks so much. This really helps a lot.Kindly give me guidelines on how to work on the second problem.